# Lua - Sorting nested array within a table

Tags: arrays, sorting, lua

I have a table in Lua that contains arrays like follows:

```
lines = 
{
    {"red", "blue", "green", "yellow"},
    {1,4,3,2}
}
```

I need to sort the table in order of 2nd array so it ends up like the following:

```
lines = 
{
    {"red", "yellow", "green", "blue"},
    {1,2,3,4}
}
```

I'm trying to use table.sort like below, but this seems to want to compare the string to an int:

```
table.sort(lines, function (a, b)
  return a[2]<b[2]
end)
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the second line the usual way
and after that set the correct order in the first line according to the second line

```
local lines = {
   {"red", "blue", "green", "yellow"},
   {1,4,3,2}
}

local tmp = {}
for j = 1, #lines[2] do
   tmp[lines[2][j]] = lines[1][j]
end
table.sort(lines[2])
for j = 1, #lines[2] do
   lines[1][j] = tmp[lines[2][j]]
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You are doing it bad.
The function `table.sort(list, comp)` orders the elements of the given table and you are sorting the `lines` table, so is "sorting" the two tables you have with each other instead of sorting each one, the correct way should be:

```lua
table.sort(lines[1])
table.sort(lines[2])
```

Assuming you will add more tables to your list would be:

```lua
for _, v in ipairs(lines) do
    table.sort(v)
end
```

Edit:
This is the real solution:

```lua
local new = {}
for i, v in ipairs(lines[2]) do
    new[i] = lines[1][v]
end
lines[1] = new
```

Comment: The thing is that I need the 2nd table to be one that orders the 1st table. So I don't want to do `table.sort(lines[1])` because that would sort the 1st table in alphabetical order. The 1st table always needs to be "tied" to the 2nd table.

Comment: Let me understand, do you wanna reorder the first table as is ordered the second?

Comment: Yes - reorder the first table according to the numerical sorted integers in the 2nd table.

After sorting, the first table should be:

`{"red", "yellow", "green", "blue"}` and the second table should be `{1,2,3,4}`

Comment: In that case, don't use the sort function, do it manually like this
`local new = {}; for i, v in ipairs(lines[2]) do; new[i] = lines[1][v]; end; lines[1] = new`